# how to combine two if conditions in google sheets script to select cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a product sheet with product code in column A, price in sterling in column C and price in euro in column D. On the quotation sheet when I enter the product code in column A and enter currency in column c, I require the code to get the price value from the appropriate currency column in the products sheet. The code I have wrote is getting the price value from the products sheet okay but I am unable to get the code to select the correct price value based on currency. Can anyone please assist? Thanks

```
function updateData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var quotationsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('QUOTATION');
  var productSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS");
  var lastProd = productSheet.getLastRow();
  var priceList = productSheet.getRange(2,1,lastProd,4).getValues();
  var drg = quotationsSheet.getRange(2, 1, quotationsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4);

  var newPrice = quotationsSheet.getLastRow();
  quotationsSheet.getRange(newPrice,2).setValue("Not found");
  var code = quotationsSheet.getRange(newPrice,1).getValue();
  var vs = drg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,j) => {
  let currency = r[2];
  for (j = 0;j <priceList.length;j++){
      
      if (priceList[j][0] == code && currency !='STERLING' ){
        var description = priceList[j][1];
        var price = priceList[j][2];
      if (priceList[j][0] == code && currency !='EURO' )
        var description = priceList[j][1];
        var price = priceList[j][3];  
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newPrice,12).setValue(description)
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newPrice,13).setValue(price)
      } 
    }
    });}
```

Comment: You should use either `forEach` or `for`, but not both of them. Besides, your `if` statement should have problems that the scope seems inappropriate.

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var quotationsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('QUOTATION');
  var productsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS");
  var lastprod = productsSheet.getLastRow();
  var productList = productsSheet.getRange(2,1,lastprod,4).getValues();
  var currencyType = quotationsSheet.getLastRow();
  var ct = quotationsSheet.getRange(currencyType,3,1,4);
  var gs = ct.getValue();
  var ge = ct.getValue();

  var newProd = quotationsSheet.getLastRow();
  quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,2).setValue("Not found");
  var code = quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,1).getValue();

  for (j = 0;j <productList.length;j++){
  //for (i = 0;i <gs.length;i++)
      if (productList[j][0] == code && gs == 'STERLING'){
        var description = productList[j][1];
        var price = productList[j][2];  
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,6).setValue(description)
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,7).setValue(price)
      } } 
   for (j = 0;j <productList.length;j++)   
     if (productList[j][0] == code && ge == 'EURO'){
        var description = productList[j][1];
        var price = productList[j][3];  
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,6).setValue(description)
        quotationsSheet.getRange(newProd,7).setValue(price) 
     }
   }```
````

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.